# Code Collaborator on Linux fails to recognize server

Tags: linux, code-collaborator

My team has just started using code collaborator.  On my Windows home machine I am able to create and add commits to reviews using the client.  On my Ubuntu work machine, when I try to connect the client to the server, I get the following error message:

> Could not verify connection to Collaborator Server
>
> **Reason:** Could not connect to Collaborator Server at [url]: Does not appear to be a running Collaborator Server

Does anyone know how to get the linux client to communicate with the server after getting this error?  Clearly the server is up and running at that url because I can access the web interface.

Answer (score 1):

The error message seems to imply that there is no URL configured, so the ccollab client doesn't know what address to use when connecting to the server.  You can force a reconnect by using the login command.

```
ccollab login
```

[Configuring Code Collaborator command line client](https://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/20416/)

Also, the documentation states that Code Collaborator client stores settings in ~/.smartbear - try deleting this file to reset the client config.